# What is scratchpad memory?

Tags: memory

What is a [scratchpad memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchpad_memory)?
I mean I get the article in principle, but I can't figure out how it exactly differs from other memories e.g. L1 Cache.
It

> is a high-speed internal memory used for temporary storage of
> calculations, data, and other work in progress.

is no explanation for me. From my pov this could be applied to almost each kind of memory.

Comment: It does not depend on the memory type, just the use of handy memory that can be shared by any chosen apps. So it has multiple input and output destinations, either serial or parallel and half or full duplex. One might also call it a register array for temporary use. You define the interface.

Comment: If you learn more about the other kinds of memory...how fast they are, how much power they consume, whether they are nonvolatile, where they are located...you will see why this description makes sense. Scratchpad memory is faster than any cache and accesses don't go through a TLB.

Comment: It can simply be an agreed-upon corner of a general purpose memory reserved for temporary results.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks a lot, Tony! Just to ensure: Each memory which serves as memory for different units is a scratchpad? This sounds so trivial why this fancy labelling then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchpad_memory

Comment: I've seen that but thanks. If I would understand it (by reading the article), I wouldn't have asked in the first place.

Comment: Can U think of a better name?  The link only shows the most popular uses.

Comment: "shared memory"? SMEM? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratchpad memory isn't a "type" of memory. It is the purpose the memory is used for, but any type of memory could be used for that purpose.

Semiconductor marketing of course picked up on this confusion long ago: if there's a "market", we shall fill it, and thus you had products designated as scratchpad (or cache!) RAM - they were simply "small" static RAMs, fast enough per whatever the marketing folk thought the typical scratchpad/cache use calls for. It's all marketing though: scratchpad/cache is what you make of it, not what it is :) And thus cache tag RAM wasn't merely called "cache RAM", it was called tag RAM, because "cache RAM" was already the way fast SRAM in narrow DIP packages was peddled at the time.

Comment: thank you, it's quite confusing.. :) Does the name even has a meaning?